# Why am I getting the error "expected primary-expression before ';' token" in my class

Tags: c++, class, token

I'm trying to make a c++ class that stores employee details in and array and when a new employee is added the array increments in size to accommodate for the new user. I'm pretty certain the code should work, but I don't understand why I'm getting this error on line 17, usually it's because I've forgotten a ';' somewhere but I've checked it 6/7 times and I can't find a missing ;.

```
struct employee
{
    int userID;
    string name;
};

class userDB {
    private:
    employee *user;
    int userSize;
public:
    userDB(employee, employee)
        :userSize(0)
    {
        userSize++;
        user= new employee[userSize];
        user[0]=employee;
    };

    ~userDB()
    {
        delete[] user;
    };

    void showUserDB()
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<userSize;i++)
        {
            cout<<user[i].userID<<": "<<user[i].name<<endl;
        }
    };

    void addNewUser(employee, employee)
    {
        int newUserDBSize=userSize+1;
        employee* newUser=new employee[newUserDBSize];
        for(int i=0;i<userSize;++i)
        {
            newUser[i]=user[i];
        };
        newUser[newUserDBSize-1]=employee;
        delete[] userDB;
        userDB = newUser;
        userSize = newUserDBSize;
    };
};
```

Comment: Do `#include <string>` and write `std::string name;`

Comment: `user[0]=employee;` makes no sense, employee is a type.

Answer (score 0):

This constructor

```
userDB(employee, employee)
    :userSize(0)
{
    userSize++;
    user= new employee[userSize];
    user[0]=employee;
};
```

is invalid at least because its parameters are not used and in statement

```
    user[0]=employee;
```

there is used type name `employee`. Maybe you mean the following

```
userDB(employee employee)
    :userSize(0)
{
    userSize++;
    user= new struct employee[userSize];
    user[0]=employee;
};
```

Though it is a bad idea when name of an object has the same name as a type name.

The same problem exists with the declaration of function addNewUser

```
   void addNewUser(employee, employee)
    {
    //...
```

Again maybe you mean the following

```
   void addNewUser(employee employee)
    {
    //...
```

In this case you have to use an eleborated name. That is instead of for example

```
employee* newUser=new employee[newUserDBSize];
```

you have to write

```
struct employee* newUser=new struct employee[newUserDBSize];
```

because the name of the parameter hides the name of the type in the function declaration.

And these statements

```
   delete[] userDB;
   userDB = newUser;
```

are invalid. You have data member `user` not `userDB`.

It would be much better if you rename the parameters.:)

Answer (score 0):

The following lines in your add function are wrong

```
    delete[] userDB;
    userDB = newUser;
```

I bet you meant

```
    delete[] user;
    user = newUser;
```